# erlang bind http query to ip (or interface)

Tags: node.js, http, erlang

In nodejs we have http.request(options[, callback]) with option localAddress ( Local interface to bind for network connections.). This is working pretty good. How can I implement this in Erlang? Now I use ibrowse for requests but this is not a constraint. I think I need to see how plain http in erlang works, but may be someone faced with this.

Answer (score 1):

Basic TCP in Erlang provides an option for [gen_tcp:connect/3,4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#connect-3) where you can declare a specific interface (or socket type, and a few other things).

If I only want to connect to some remote Host:Port the call looks like:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, [])
```

If I want the local side of the connection to originate from a specific address (on this machine 192.168.5.23 is wlan0, 192.168.7.67 is eth0, for example) I can do:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, [{ifaddr, {192,168,5,23}}])
```

If I want to connect from a specific port, I would add the port option:

```
Options = [{ifaddr, {192, 168, 5, 23}}, {port, 11311}],
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, Options),
```

That's just vanilla TCP. Writing an HTTP/1.1 client in Erlang is pretty easy, and depending on what you want to do may be ideal.

There is also a built-in http client called [httpc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) (and a few other somewhat more featureful/cleaner ones around like [gun](https://github.com/ninenines/gun) and [hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney)). These all [make requests](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-1) using similar arguments to gen_tcp, including availability of the same [connect options](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#type-connect_option) as well as a special [httpc:set_options/1,2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#set_options-1) that is pretty straightforward to use:

```
ok = inets:start(),
ok = httpc:set_options([{ip, {192, 168, 5, 23}}, {port, 11311}]),
{ok, Response} = httpc:request("http://zxq9.com/archives/1311"),
```

Hopefully this is enough information to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer!